# HackerRank Compare the Triplets Clojure

Tags: clojure

I cannot work out why the atom references do not keep there values of inc.

1) How to correct this?
2) Why in debugging mode it seems to give correct values?

I know this may not be optimal solution but want to understand why it is not working.

Your task is to find their comparison points by comparing a0 with b0, a1 with b1, and a2 with b2.

If a is greater than b, then Alice is awarded  point.
If a is less than b, then Bob is awarded  point.
If a equals b then neither person receives a point.

```
(defn compare-the-triplets
  [alice bob]
  (let [alice-score (atom 0)
        bob-score (atom 0)]
    (for [i (range 3)]
      (let [a (get alice i)
            b (get bob i)]
        (cond
          (> a b) (swap! alice-score inc)
          (< a b) (swap! bob-score inc))
        )) [@alice-score @bob-score]))

(compare-the-triplets [5 6 7] [3 6 10])
```

When I run it it returns 0 and 0 for the Atom. I feel this may not be the best answer but its really annoying why the debug works and gets the atoms at the correct value but then they are not returned correctly.

Using the scope of let and for here must not be correct.

Comment: `(compare-the-triplets [5 6 7] [3 6 10])` gives me `[0 0]`, your expected result should have been `[1 1]` is that your question?

Comment: @prayagupd yes correctness? but also why it seems to show correct values when debugging

Comment: ;; I'd use a SICP-style accumulator parameter + recursion and avoid mutability altogether. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct!

for yields a lazy sequence: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for

See the use of dorun in the for documentation, or use doseq instead of for.

Comment: Actually that seems like the problem thanks testing out now

Comment: Thanks if you want to add a more functional solution that be nice, but that was it. Hence why when evaluating with debugger it did process the lazy sequence

Answer (score 5):

This is venturing into review territory, but I think it should be emphasized that atoms are not the right tool here. There's no leakage of side effects, but their use unnecessarily bloats everything up, and goes against common functional practice.

Since this is basically just a reduction, that's what I think would be the neatest here. You have a collection (or in this case, two), and need to accumulate a value (or again, in this case, two). Whenever this is the case, `reduce` should come to mind:

```
(defn compare-the-triplets2 [alice bob]
  (reduce (fn [scores [al bo]]
            ; If the condition on the left is true, update either the 0th or 1st score
            (cond-> scores
              (> al bo) (update 0 inc)
              (< al bo) (update 1 inc)))

          ; Both start with a score of 0
          [0 0]

          ; Zip alice and bob together, then reduce over the zipped collection
          (map vector alice bob)))
```

The fact that it's possible for a tie complicates things, but [`cond->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond-%3E) handles it well. Unfortunately, `cond->` doesn't short circuit like `cond` does, so this will be slightly less efficient. Unless this proves to be time critical code though, the time difference should be beyond negligible.

Note the use of `update`, and how similar it is to your use of `swap!`. In this case though, I'm using 0 and 1 to indicate which score in the vector accumulator to increment.

Comment: cond-> looks really good let me take a look, thanks this is a great help also